# Api Platform renaming class when generating Documentation?

Tags: symfony, entity, api-platform.com

i have a problem on a project i'm working on, when i try to access the default /api for Api Platform/Symfony.
The error ocurrs when the documentation page is loaded and cache has already been produced.
I checked the project i don't load it as 'survey' anywhere, the error comes clearly after the cache is generated.
Ex: i clean the cache => 1st /api load goes well, any further loads of /api trigger the error.

I get this error:
Class App\Entity\survey does not exist
https://i.stack.imgur.com/83pK7.png

Here is the declaration of said entity:

```
namespace App\Entity;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use App\Repository\SurveyRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;
 /**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=SurveyRepository::class)
 * @ApiResource(
 *     normalizationContext={
 *         "groups"={"survey_read"}
 *     },
 *     denormalizationContext={
 *          "groups"={"survey_write"}
 *     },
 *     collectionOperations={
 *          "get"={
 *              "security"="is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN')"
 *          },
 *          "post"={
 *              "security"="is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN')"
 *          }
 *     },
 *     itemOperations={
 *          "get"={
 *              "security"="is_granted('ROLE_USER')"
 *          },
 *          "delete"={
 *              "security"="is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN')"
 *          },
 *          "patch"={
 *              "security"="is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN')"
 *          }
 *     }
 * )
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Survey
```

It's pretty basic config so i don't know what's going on.
If someone has a similar error with a fix? or some url where i would find an answer.
Thanks !!

Comment: what's teh file called?

Comment: also ... which namespace does the class have

Comment: `App\Entity\survey` Vs. `App\Entity\Survey` you must be calling it `survey` somewhere instead of `Survey`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was mispelling in another entity association with this one.

My question now is how it didn't trigger an error in the 1st time?